# Getting SHA256 in base64 format using DigestUtils

Tags: java, hash, base64, sha256

I'm trying to get the SHA256 hash of a string in base64 format.

I'm using `DigestUtils` from `org.apache.commons.codec.digest`. I don't know how to get the Base64 format, even though I can get the Hex format.

```
Sha256String = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(StringText);
```

Using `"a"` as stringtest, this line returns

```
ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb
```

But what I actually need is `ypeBEsobvcr6wjGzmiPcTaeG7/gUfE5yuYB3ha/uSLs`.

I have been reading nonstop, and can't understand how to do it.

Now I'm trying this

```
Byte[] digest = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256(StringText);
```

And this I need to store it in a variable, so I'm trying this

```
String OutStr = new String(digest);
```

With no luck. I don't know where else to search help, for I had read all the google searches a lot of times (and if the answer is there, I'm not seeing it)

I don't code in java, but this time I need this to get working! Love!

Comment: eventually feeding that `byte[]` into [`Base64.Encoder.encodeToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Base64.Encoder.encodeToString()` method to convert the byte array into a `Base64`.

Here is a short example: (since I am not familiar with your util, just replace the some data with your byte array)

```
byte[] data = someData;
MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
digester.update(data);
String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digester.digest());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I made it thanks to both of you @Carlos Heuberger